# jQuery multiple versions noConflict in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery

I have a javascript widget that I wrote using jQuery 1.8 that loads on a clients website that uses jQuery 1.3. I cannot get noConflict working properly in IE without some really ugly hacks.  Here is what the page looks like after my widget is rendered:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $jq = $.noConflict();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome, this works great, $jq is defined as jQuery 1.8.3, but in IE 8 this does not work, $jq is defined as jQuery 1.3. My guess is that its a timing issue, the script gets executed before the new jQuery is loaded. I put in some call back timers and it works, but I cant imagine having embedded callback timers is the right way to go.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I cannot namespace jQuery1.3, the client uses it throughout the page and does not want to upgrade.

Comment: Scripts like this are executed in the order encountered in all browsers.  That behavior is not different in any version of IE.  There must be something else causing your IE issue.

Comment: out of curiosity what is reason for needing both? Have you a plugin that won't run on 1.8? 98% of methods should be backward compatible to 1.3

Comment: Its not up to me, the client does not want to change their jQuery in order to use my widget...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with [LABjs](http://labjs.com/), which is a javascript loader. This way I can synchronously load scripts and execute code on them accordingly:

```
<script>
   $LAB
   .script("framework.js").wait()
   .script("plugin.framework.js")
   .script("myplugin.framework.js")
   .wait(function(){
      myplugin.init();
      framework.init();
      framework.doSomething();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.5 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://foo.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_5 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.6 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://foo.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_6 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

in this case -

use

```
jQuery_1_6(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

see here - http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Comment: OK, let me clear something about this. Client is running 1.3 version and they will not upgrade. But your plugin need 1.8, you client doesnt need 1.8 so you can use $ or jquery this will call 1.3 and you have to use another instance name for using different version of jquery by - <script src="jQuery1.8.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq18 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script> - so that you can use jq18 which will call 1.8 version. Your client can still use $ or jquery which will call 1.3 Correct me if i am wrong. and in your plugin please use - (function($) {
 ... 
})(jq18);

Comment: or Step 1. Load the Jquery 1.3.3 library
Step 2. Load all plugins that are supported only by Jquery 1.3.3
Step 3. Run the noConflict command for the included Jquery. $jq133 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
Step 4. Include the Jquery 1.8.3 library
Step 5. Include all plugins required and supported by Jquery 1.8.3
Step 5. Now you can used the old version of Jquery using $jq133 and new version using $